# Why is synchronized needed here?

Tags: android, multithreading

Reading through the [Android page on Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) they show an example of a rudimentary IntentService implementation. I plan on implementing something similar since it needs to bind. However, I'm confused why they need to use the synchronized block below. If someone could shed some light on that I'd be very grateful.

```
// Handler that receives messages from the thread
  private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
      public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
      }
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
          // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
          long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
          while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
              synchronized (this) {
                  try {
                      wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                  }
              }
          }
          // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
          // the service in the middle of handling another job
          stopSelf(msg.arg1);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea what wait() method does, probably sleeps the thread.  IMHO, synchronized block is obsolete, as long as wait() method does not start separate thread.

Comment: If we all get one guess, then my guess is that it is to ensure that the thread can't be interrupted while sleeping.  Nothing else can notify the thread if they can't synchronize() it.  But yeah, it seems unnecessary considering for a demo.

Comment: Plz refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892144/extending-the-intentservice-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sample is trying to simulate real `IntentService` for example downloading a file. consider this story:
you ask it to download a file, as it is commented in the code it simulates that by waiting just 5ms. In order to call wait function you need a synchronized block. Why?
because if you do not it throws [IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)